# Linux 3.14 policy when closing file handles of a program that exited prematurely

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel

Assume a situation where a program opens a memory mapped file for writing. Immediately after writing the content to the file, it calls exit(0). Now my question is what does the kernel does in this case ? Does it flushes the content of the memory mapped region to the file while closing the file descriptor or it discards what is in the buffer ?

Answer (score 2):

Neither. It does not discard the data. The data mapped through the file/page cache in the kernel, and will be flushed to the disk at a time the kernel finds convenient (or until your program explicitly issues an msync() call). This is pretty much the same as what happens if you do normal write() on a file descriptor, and close() that file descriptor, or exit the program.

Keep in mind, access to that file goes through the same kernel cache, so other processes will see the data you've written immediately whether the process crashes or not. (subject perhaps to memory barriers though).

Comment: Of course, it also depends on the exact arguments `mmap()` was called with to begin with. There are cases where the writes would be essentially ignored as well (i.e. `MAP_PRIVATE` or `MAP_ANONYMOUS`)...

Comment: @nos This is actually not true for linux 3.14 kernel.I created a program to test this. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/04/28/10003540.aspx The views outlined here is actually true in practice for linux 3.14.

Comment: @gibraltar It sounds like this answer and the blog post you reference agree.  What behavior do you think this answer describes which is not true?

Comment: @Peter I think the kernel discards the data of a memory mapped region if there is just one viewer. Though I agree I am bit confused by kernel convenience. Does this imply it will flush the data or it has a choice of either flushing or not flushing ?

Comment: The blog post does not say that.  It goes through several long-winded arguments about why it makes sense for a kernel to NOT discard changes in the case of abnormal termination.  Summary: because the kernel would have to work hard to handle a special case that no one wants anyway.  "convenient" means it will flush the data at some point, just like any other dirty page that is backed by a file.

Comment: Well, albeit linux does it in a very similar way, that blog post isn't overly relevant, since it's about the windows kernel.